# Save detected QR code from live video stream as an image using Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and OpenCV 2 in which I have to detect a QR code and save it as an Image, I have done the detection part successfully but don't know how can I save the QR code as an Image?

Here's what I have tried so far:

The detection part of code:

```
while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
    barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)

    for barcode in barcodes:
        (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
        barcodeType = barcode.type
        text = "{}".format(barcodeData)
        cv2.putText(frame, '', (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        if barcodeData not in found:
            csv.write("{}\n".format(barcodeData))
            csv.flush()

            found.clear()
            found.add(barcodeData)

    # Título do Frame
    cv2.imshow("Live Stream Window", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

How can I save the detected area (QR code) as an Image?

> **Update:** below is the updated code to svae image automatically, but this is not working.

```
while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
    original = frame.copy()
    barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)
    barcode_num = 0
    frame_dict = {'y': 0, 'w': 0, 'h': 0, 'x': 0}

    for barcode in barcodes:
        (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
        print(f'{x}, {y}, {w}, {h}')
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        ROI = original[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        frame_dict['y'] = y
        frame_dict['x'] = x
        frame_dict['h'] = h
        frame_dict['w'] = w
        barcode_num += 1
        barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
        print(barcodeData)
        barcodeType = barcode.type
        text = "{}".format(barcodeData)
        cv2.putText(frame, '', (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        if barcodeData not in found:
            csv.write("{}\n".format(barcodeData))
            csv.flush()

            found.clear()
            found.add(barcodeData)

    cv2.imshow("Live Stream Window", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("c"):
        print('c is pressed')
        ROI = original[frame_dict['y']:frame_dict['y'] + frame_dict['h'],
                       frame_dict['x']:frame_dict['x'] + frame_dict['w']]
        cv2.imwrite('barcode_{}.png'.format(barcode_num), ROI)
        pass
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python OpenCV live face detection crop saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408414/python-opencv-live-face-detection-crop-saved)

Answer (score 2):

With the assumption that `(x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect` returns the same values as `x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)`, here's a visualization for cropping a ROI from an image

```
-------------------------------------------
|                                         | 
|    (x1, y1)                             |
|      ------------------------           |
|      |                      |           |
|      |                      |           | 
|      |         ROI          |           |  
|      |                      |           |   
|      |                      |           |   
|      |                      |           |       
|      ------------------------           |   
|                           (x2, y2)      |    
|                                         |             
|                                         |             
|                                         |             
-------------------------------------------
```

Consider `(0,0)` as the top-left corner of the image with left-to-right as the x-direction and top-to-bottom as the y-direction. If we have `(x1,y1)` as the top-left and `(x2,y2)` as the bottom-right vertex of a ROI, we can use Numpy slicing to crop the image with:

```
ROI = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```

But normally we will not have the bottom-right vertex. In typical cases, we will be iterating through contours where the rectangular ROI coordinates can be found with [`cv2.boundingRect()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect). Additionally, if we wanted to save multiple ROIs, we could keep a counter

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(grayscale_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
    ROI_number += 1
```

---

Going back to your problem, here's how we can do it. Note we make a copy of the frame `original = frame.copy()` because once we draw on the image using `cv2.rectangle`, it will paint onto the frame. When we crop it, we don't want this painted frame so we crop from a copy of the frame.

```
while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
    original = frame.copy()
    barcodes = pyzbar.decode(frame)
    barcode_num = 0

    for barcode in barcodes:
        (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite('barcode_{}.png'.format(barcode_num), ROI)
        barcode_num += 1
        barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
        barcodeType = barcode.type
        text = "{}".format(barcodeData)
        cv2.putText(frame, '', (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        if barcodeData not in found:
            csv.write("{}\n".format(barcodeData))
            csv.flush()

            found.clear()
            found.add(barcodeData)

    # TÃ­tulo do Frame
    cv2.imshow("Live Stream Window", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Comment: I have tried your code, it's capturing the image when I press the "q" key, mean quit the program, how can we automatically capture the image in live stream without pressing the "q" key and also can we improve the quality of captured image?

Comment: You can add another check if some other key was pressed to manually save frames. If you want to automatically capture the image, create a timer to periodically save frames. I can't say exactly what to do on how to improve the quality of your image without knowing your setup and having sample images

Comment: can you update your code to automatically capture the image periodically?

Comment: I have tried by adding a new waitKey but it's not working. You can see the updated code in the question.

Comment: If you want to automatically capture the image, take out the way key and save the image for each frame