# Mouse input outside the window

Tags: python, mouse

I am trying to figure out how to replace keyboard press into mouse left click..
I tried pynput, but for somewhat reason it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone help with this?

- IS there a way to receive this input even while doing something else? For example browsing the internet and still getting screenshots when mouse is clicked.

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

cv2.namedWindow("test")

img_counter = 0

while True:
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if not ret:
        print("failed to grab frame")
        break
    cv2.imshow("test", frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k%256 == 27:
        # ESC pressed
        print("Escape hit, closing...")
        break
    elif k%256 == 32:
        # SPACE pressed
        img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        img_counter += 1

cam.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opencv: detect mouse position clicking over a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327020/opencv-detect-mouse-position-clicking-over-a-picture)

Comment: Went through the post u linked,, but tbh can't understand what's going on. Sorry.@JohnnyMopp

Comment: Or..relate.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62142678/19130615  this code and add a condition of only capture if mouse is clicked?